# How do you listen to keydown on Backbone events method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is the equivalent of this `$(document).on('keydown', this.logKey);` for Backbone `events:{}`?  I am asking because I rather bind all events at once place rather than put some in the **initialize** method.

I tried the suggestion here: [how to capture the key event from a view ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033010/how-to-capture-the-key-event-from-a-view) I.e. `events{'keydown' : 'logKey'}`.  This is not working for me though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS selectors defined in the [View.delegateEvents()](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) are bounded to the context of `View.$el` so if you want the View to manage the events on `document` the `View.$el` should be `document` itself:

```
// code no tested
var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "document",
  events: {
    "keydown": "theHandler"
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks! that's very interesting because I tried `'keydown document':'logkey'` and it didn't work. I guess it has to be at `el: 'document'`.

Comment: If the target DOM element of the event is the own root `el` you don't have to specify the DOM element